# Replace strings with text with GNU ed

Tags: gnu, ed

I want to replace `%foo%` (found in file test) with a string containing every possible character. Because of the missing character limitation, the following is not possible (executed in BASHv4):

```
echo %foo% > test
replacement="//this//is//a//test"
ed -s test <<< "g/%foo%/s/%foo%/$replacement"
```

Any idea how to replace `%foo%` with every possible text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With command `r` it is possible to load text from another file, so the following is a valid solution:

- store replacement to another file
- open file with ed
- move pointer to location
- delete line (fake replace follows)
- load text from file with `r FILE`
- write and quit

Answer (score 1):

I'll warrant the guess that you will get pretty close to your goal by escaping slashes and backslashes with a prepended backslash each. AFAIK that can't be done in bash in a single step, so you can either write a function to make it readable, or enjoy your trip to the leaning toothpick forest:

```
$ echo %foo% > test
$ replacement="//this//is//a\\\\//test"
$ echo $replacement
//this//is//a\\//test
$ stage1=${replacement//\\/\\\\}
$ echo $stage1
//this//is//a\\\\//test
$ stage2=${stage1//\//\\\/}
$ echo $stage2
\/\/this\/\/is\/\/a\\\\\/\/test
$ ed -s test <<< g/.*foo.*/s/foo/$stage2/p
%//this//is//a\\//test%
```

Newlines remain a problem, but then you don't want to keep them in bash environment variables anyway since whitespace isnt' very stable there.